# How do I remove the white background and keep the shadows with a transparent background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, background-removal, shadows

How do I remove the white background and keep the shadows with a transparent background?[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  We aren't really a tutorial site, but if you give us a specific issue, we can help you more.

Comment: You would be WAY better off selecting only the object and then recreating the shadow.

Comment: Oh, in fact... I think this is a nice question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. On the top menu bar click on **Select > Color Range** (with this tool, you can select the white background)
2. With the tool opened `Shift + Click` to add more white color. This lets you select the entire range of the white color
3. Click **Ok** to confirm
4. Press `Ctrl + Shift + I` to invert your selection
5. Select your layer and create a layer mask
6. Done! You've removed the white background and the shadows are still there

You may have to make some adjustments to the layer because the white is still on the shadows... also the square has white too, and color range tool selects the white color on the whole image, so you have to fill the layer mask with a white brush tool (opacity 100%) on the area of the square (you have to click on the mask), or just select the square with the rectangle selection tool and make it visible with the white brush.